# EMI input filter for DC/DC converter

Tags: dc-dc-converter, emc, emi-filtering

In my design I want to convert a 48V input voltage to a 12V output voltage. In order to achieve this I want to use the [AVD120-48S12-6L](https://4donline.ihs.com/images/VipMasterIC/IC/ATSN/ATSN-S-A0009783886/ATSN-S-A0009783925-1.pdf?hkey=52A5661711E402568146F3353EA87419). The following external circuit is stated as recommended:[image]

However, I am not sure why the transformer is needed, since in most circuits a simple inductor is used. Can someone maybe explain this to me?

Comment: It's a common mode choke, for common mode noise filtering.

Comment: Linkyyy nailed it, CM Choke. A simple inductor is good for filtering Differential Mode noise. DM noise is noise whose current flows in the path of your circuit, in this case from RTN to -48V. CM noise flows through both RTN and -48V and then to some other return path (usually parasitic). A DM choke will do nothing for CM noise. A CM choke will have a differential leakage inductance which will do some small amount of DM filtering as well.